# Flexbox Alignment Issue in Sign-In Container with Flipper Feature Toggle

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, flexbox

I'm encountering a layout problem on web page when using the Flipper gem for feature toggling. In the default state (Flipper disabled), I have both sign-up and sign-in containers, and they are correctly centered. However, when the :one_login feature is enabled using Flipper, only the sign-in container is visible, but it's not centered; it appears on the left side of the page.

I suspect this might be due to the changes in the container structure when Flipper is enabled. The relevant code snippet looks like this:

```
<div class="container box login d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="container login d-flex m-0 p-0">
    <% unless Flipper.enabled?(:one_login) %>
      <div class="d-flex sign_up_container align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="sign_up w-100 h-100 login d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="sign_up_text login">
            <h1><%= t('user_session.signin.create_account_msg', default: 'Register') %></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-2 sign_up_link login cancel_btn">
            <%= link_to t('user_session.signin.create_account', default: 'New account'), new_user_path %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="d-flex sign_in_container align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div class="sign_in w-100 h-100 login d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <h1>
          <% if @force_email %>
            <%= t('user_session.signin.user_found_title', default: 'Enter password') %>
          <% else %>
            <%= t('user_session.signin.form_title', default: 'Enter your name') %>
          <% end %>
        </h1>
```

I've attempted to modify the structure by introducing a flex-column container, but the alignment issue persists. Can someone help me ensure that the sign-in container is centered even when the sign-up container is not visible due to Flipper being enabled?

Comment: It sounds like you use `visibility` visible and hidden, remember it still takes the space when hidden. Try `display` none to hide it completely